# Building android projects in netbeans with gradle support

Tags: android, gradle

I know that Android Studio is now the official IDE for developing Android apps, but my computer is really slow and I find it difficult to use Android Studio on it.

I'm using Netbeans for Android apps development and fortunately it works fine.

The problem I am having now is using the Android support libraries in netbeans. I found out that Android now uses the Gradle system for apps development in which the dependencies are declared, but the apps that that Netbeans creates don't have a Gradle file and I won't be able to add the dependencies.

My question is:

- How do I create Gradle files in Netbeans?
- Or how can I add the support libraries directly into my Netbeans projects without the need for Gradle?

I have downloaded the support libraries and I have also installed Gradle on my computer.